# Java-GUI Key Pressed Not Functioning Correctly

Tags: java, image, user-interface, move

So I looked at tons of different threads about this but all of the suggestions of how to make it work; I have done, so it should work. I have gotten it to work before, and I am doing the same thing as when I had images move in another program of mine. Anyways, this is a space shooter like game. I am working on the class in charge of the player vs player. You will see the comment for spacebar and key 'e' will have a shooting in added for later. Shooting is another class, that way I can rapid fire and can control each bullet because there independent objects. Anyways, I did some test with printing out stuff, and I know the timer works. I know the move method is working, because I see my images move on screen. However, I have no control. I then put a print statement in the key pressed area, and it is not printing anything. So I know that is the code that is somehow wrong. So any help would be great as I am stumped. This is not for a class in college or high school. It is a personal project. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class PlayervsPlayer implements KeyListener,ActionListener{

    private JFrame window;
    private Timer timer;
    private int win_size;
    private int ship_clearence=45;
    private int speed=3;
    private final int stop1=0;
    private final int stop2=1;
    private final int left1=2;
    private final int left2=3;
    private final int right1=4;
    private final int right2=5;
    private int dir1=left1;
    private int dir2=right2;
    Sprite background;
    Sprite ship1=new Sprite("Spaceship.png");
    Sprite ship2=new Sprite("Spaceship2.png");

    public PlayervsPlayer(JFrame w,Sprite backdrop,int win_s) {
        window=w;
        background=backdrop;
        win_size=win_s;
        window.addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void pvpmain() {
        System.out.println("Player vs Player working!");
        ship1.setSize(125,125);
        ship1.setLocation((int)((win_size/2)-(ship1.getWidth()/2)),win_size-ship1.getHeight()-ship_clearence);
        ship2.setSize(125,125);
        ship2.setLocation((int)((win_size/2)-(ship1.getWidth()/2)),0);
        window.add(ship1,0);
        window.add(ship2,0);
        window.repaint();
        timer = new Timer( 10, this );
        timer.start();
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key=e.getKeyCode();
        if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ){
            System.out.println("Right Key");//
            dir1 = right1;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dir1=left1;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            //Nothing for now as for shooting
        }
        if (key==KeyEvent.VK_Q) {
            dir2=left2;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            dir2=right2;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_E) {
            //Nothing for now as for shooting
        }
    }
    public void move() {
        if (dir1==left1) {
            if (ship1.getX()<=speed) {
                dir1=stop1;
            }
            else {
                ship1.setLocation(ship1.getX()-speed,ship1.getY());
            }
        }
        else if (dir1==right1) {
            if (ship1.getX()+ship1.getWidth()>=win_size-speed) {
                dir1=stop1;
            }
            else {
                ship1.setLocation(ship1.getX()+speed,ship1.getY());
            }
        }
        if (dir2==left2) {
            if (ship2.getX()<=speed) {
                dir2=stop2;
            }
            else {
                ship2.setLocation(ship2.getX()-speed,ship2.getY());
            }
        }
        else if (dir2==right2) {
            if (ship2.getX()+ship2.getWidth()>=win_size-speed) {
                dir2=stop2;
            }
            else {
                ship2.setLocation(ship2.getX()+speed,ship2.getY());
            }
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ( e.getSource() == timer ){
            System.out.println("Timer Working!");
            move();
        }

    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        //Nothing

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        //Nothing

    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary issue is related to the fact that `KeyListener` is unreliable in the application you are trying to use it.  `KeyListener` requires that the component it is registered to is capable of receiving keyboard focus AND has keyboard focus before it will trigger key events.  It's very easy for focus to be stolen by other components.

The most reliable solution to your problem is to make use of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which was in part, developed to solve this very issue.

You may also want to have a read of [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to understand how this part of the API works

So, adapting the code from [Trying to move JLabels on a JPanel with GridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585343/trying-to-move-jlabels-on-a-jpanel-with-gridlayout/34585504#34585504), which is the simplest example which is most closely aligned with what you seem to be trying to do, you could end up with something like...

[image: Move It]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel player;

        public TestPane() {
            player = makeLabel("P");
            player.setSize(player.getPreferredSize());
            add(player);

            addKeyBinding("left", KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, new MoveAction(player, -4, 0));
            addKeyBinding("right", KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, new MoveAction(player, 4, 0));
            addKeyBinding("up", KeyEvent.VK_UP, new MoveAction(player, 0, -4));
            addKeyBinding("down", KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, new MoveAction(player, 0, 4));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(String name, int keyCode, Action action) {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0), name);
            actionMap.put(name, action);
        }

        protected JLabel makeLabel(String text) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
                    new LineBorder(Color.GRAY),
                    new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4)));
            return label;
        }

        public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

            private final int xDelta, yDelta;
            private final JComponent component;

            public MoveAction(JComponent component, int xDelta, int yDelta) {
                this.component = component;
                this.xDelta = xDelta;
                this.yDelta = yDelta;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Point location = component.getLocation();
                location.x += xDelta;
                location.y += yDelta;
                component.setLocation(location);
                repaint();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

> But what about multiple, simultaneous, key stokes?

Well, this isn't a unique problem, which is most commonly solved by using a series of flags which determine if a key is currently been pressed or not.  You then use these flags to make determinations about how best to move the object

So, adapting from the first example, you might end up with something like...

[image: Move it two]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test2();
    }

    public Test2() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum Direction {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    public class Controller {
        private Set<Direction> directions;
        private JComponent player;

        public Controller(JComponent player) {
            this.player = player;
            directions = new TreeSet<>();
        }

        public void released(Direction direction) {
            directions.remove(direction);
            updatePosition();
        }

        public void pressed(Direction direction) {
            directions.add(direction);
            updatePosition();
        }

        protected void updatePosition() {
            Point location = player.getLocation();
            if (directions.contains(Direction.UP)) {
                location.y -= 4;
            } 
            if (directions.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
                location.y += 4;
            }
            if (directions.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                location.x -= 4;
            } 
            if (directions.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                location.x += 4;
            }
            player.setLocation(location);
        }

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel player;

        public TestPane() {
            player = makeLabel("P");
            player.setSize(player.getPreferredSize());
            add(player);

            Controller controller = new Controller(player);

            addKeyBinding("left", KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, Direction.LEFT, controller);
            addKeyBinding("right", KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, Direction.RIGHT, controller);
            addKeyBinding("up", KeyEvent.VK_UP, Direction.UP, controller);
            addKeyBinding("down", KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, Direction.DOWN, controller);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(String name, int keyCode, Direction direction, Controller controller) {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true), name + "-released");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false), name + "-pressed");

            actionMap.put(name + "-released", new MoveAction(direction, controller, true));
            actionMap.put(name + "-pressed", new MoveAction(direction, controller, false));
        }

        protected JLabel makeLabel(String text) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
                    new LineBorder(Color.GRAY),
                    new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4)));
            return label;
        }

        public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

            private Direction direction;
            private Controller controller;
            private boolean released;

            public MoveAction(Direction direction, Controller controller, boolean released) {
                this.direction = direction;
                this.controller = controller;
                this.released = released;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (released) {
                    controller.released(direction);
                } else {
                    controller.pressed(direction);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

> Next time, try to work with some ones code instead of forcing them to restructure and make a suggestion to use this key binding thing. If you think key binding is so great, why don't you modify my code with key binding instead, lets see how complicated it is then

*Sigh* - Because I shouldn't have to, even in your own words, you didn't want a "copy and paste" answer, but, apparent that is what you want ...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

// I'd prefer to extend from JPanel, as it provides bases for
// self contained responsibility, but apparently, that's too "advanced"
public class PlayervsPlayer implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame window;
    private Timer timer;
    private int win_size;
    private int ship_clearence = 45;
    private int speed = 3;
    private final int stop1 = 0;
    private final int stop2 = 1;
    private final int left1 = 2;
    private final int left2 = 3;
    private final int right1 = 4;
    private final int right2 = 5;
    private int dir1 = left1;
    private int dir2 = right2;
//  Sprite background;
    JLabel ship1 = new JLabel("Spaceship.png");
    JLabel ship2 = new JLabel("Spaceship2.png");

    public PlayervsPlayer(JFrame w, int win_s) {
        window = w;
//      background = backdrop;
        win_size = win_s;

        JComponent contenPane = (JComponent) w.getContentPane();

        InputMap inputMap = contenPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = contenPane.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "player1-left");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "player1-right");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "player2-left");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, 0), "player2-right");

        // I'd prefer a single "Move Action" class which could
        // make these updates, but that might be "too advanced"
        actionMap.put("player1-left", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Player 1 - left");
                dir1 = left1;
            }
        });
        actionMap.put("player1-right", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Player 1 - right");
                dir1 = right1;
            }
        });
        actionMap.put("player2-left", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Player 2 - left");
                dir2 = left2;
            }
        });
        actionMap.put("player2-right", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Player 2 - right");
                dir2 = right2;
            }
        });
    }

    public void pvpmain() {
        System.out.println("Player vs Player working!");
        ship1.setSize(125, 125);
        ship1.setLocation((int) ((win_size / 2) - (ship1.getWidth() / 2)), win_size - ship1.getHeight() - ship_clearence);
        ship2.setSize(125, 125);
        ship2.setLocation((int) ((win_size / 2) - (ship1.getWidth() / 2)), 0);
        window.add(ship1, 0);
        window.add(ship2, 0);
        window.repaint();
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void move() {
        if (dir1 == left1) {
            if (ship1.getX() <= speed) {
                dir1 = stop1;
            } else {
                ship1.setLocation(ship1.getX() - speed, ship1.getY());
            }
        } else if (dir1 == right1) {
            if (ship1.getX() + ship1.getWidth() >= win_size - speed) {
                dir1 = stop1;
            } else {
                ship1.setLocation(ship1.getX() + speed, ship1.getY());
            }
        }
        if (dir2 == left2) {
            if (ship2.getX() <= speed) {
                dir2 = stop2;
            } else {
                ship2.setLocation(ship2.getX() - speed, ship2.getY());
            }
        } else if (dir2 == right2) {
            if (ship2.getX() + ship2.getWidth() >= win_size - speed) {
                dir2 = stop2;
            } else {
                ship2.setLocation(ship2.getX() + speed, ship2.getY());
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == timer) {
            System.out.println("Timer Working!");
            move();
        }
    }

}
```

> But the players won't stop moving when you release a key...

Hmm, yes, that is true, but the original code didn't seem to have that functionality either

So, in the `PlayervsPlayer` constructor, we'd replace the existing bindings with something more like...

```
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "player1-left-pressed");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "player1-right-pressed");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "player2-left-pressed");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, 0, false), "player2-right-pressed");

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "player1-left-released");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "player1-right-released");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "player2-left-released");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, 0, true), "player2-right-released");

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "space");

    // I'd prefer this to be a self containted unit of work, but for demonstration purposes
    actionMap.put("player1-left-pressed", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 - left");
            dir1 = left1;
        }
    });
    actionMap.put("player1-right-pressed", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 - right");
            dir1 = right1;
        }
    });
    actionMap.put("player2-left-pressed", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 - left");
            dir2 = left2;
        }
    });
    actionMap.put("player2-right-pressed", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 - right");
            dir2 = right2;
        }
    });

    actionMap.put("player1-left-released", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 - left");
            dir1 = stop1;
        }
    });
    actionMap.put("player1-right-released", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 - stop");
            dir1 = stop1;
        }
    });
    actionMap.put("player2-left-released", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 - stop");
            dir2 = stop2;
        }
    });
    actionMap.put("player2-right-released", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 - stop");
            dir2 = stop2;
        }
    });

    actionMap.put("space", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Pew pew pew");
        }
    });
```

I also added <kbd>Space</kbd> because I forget to put it in the previous example

> I would be interested in seeing how much longer key binding is to my code

My favourite topic - reduce and reuse. As I stated in my comments above, I'd prefer to have a single "move action" class which could change some kind of state, here I've used a `Set`, but you could pass an instance of `PlayervsPlayer` and have the `MoveAction` call a method on it, telling the class what action has occurred, I prefer this method as it decouples the code (makes it more re-usable)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

// I'd prefer to extend from JPanel, as it provides bases for
// self contained responsibility, but apparently, that's too "advanced"
public class PlayervsPlayer implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLayout(null);
                new PlayervsPlayer(frame, 400).pvpmain();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private JFrame window;
    private Timer timer;
    private int win_size;
    private int ship_clearence = 45;
    private int speed = 3;
    private final int stop1 = 0;
    private final int stop2 = 1;
    private final int left1 = 2;
    private final int left2 = 3;
    private final int right1 = 4;
    private final int right2 = 5;
//  private int dir1 = left1;
//  private int dir2 = right2;
//  Sprite background;
    JLabel ship1 = new JLabel("Spaceship.png");
    JLabel ship2 = new JLabel("Spaceship2.png");

    private Set<Integer> playerKeys;

    public PlayervsPlayer(JFrame w, int win_s) {
        window = w;
//      background = backdrop;
        win_size = win_s;

        playerKeys = new TreeSet<>();
        playerKeys = new TreeSet<>();

        playerKeys.add(left1);
        playerKeys.add(right2);

        JComponent contenPane = (JComponent) w.getContentPane();

        InputMap inputMap = contenPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = contenPane.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "player1-left");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "player1-right");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "player2-left");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, 0), "player2-right");

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "player1-left-pressed");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "player1-right-pressed");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "player2-left-pressed");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, 0, false), "player2-right-pressed");

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "player1-left-released");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "player1-right-released");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "player2-left-released");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, 0, true), "player2-right-released");

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "space");

        // I'd prefer this to be a self containted unit of work, but for demonstration purposes
        actionMap.put("player1-left-pressed", new MoveAction(playerKeys, left1, false));
        actionMap.put("player1-right-pressed", new MoveAction(playerKeys, right1, false));

        actionMap.put("player2-left-pressed", new MoveAction(playerKeys, left2, false));
        actionMap.put("player2-right-pressed", new MoveAction(playerKeys, right2, false));

        actionMap.put("player1-left-released", new MoveAction(playerKeys, left1, true));
        actionMap.put("player1-right-released", new MoveAction(playerKeys, right1, true));

        actionMap.put("player2-left-released", new MoveAction(playerKeys, left2, true));
        actionMap.put("player2-right-released", new MoveAction(playerKeys, right2, true));

        actionMap.put("space", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Pew pew pew");
            }
        });
    }

    public void pvpmain() {
        System.out.println("Player vs Player working!");
        ship1.setSize(125, 125);
        ship1.setLocation((int) ((win_size / 2) - (ship1.getWidth() / 2)), win_size - ship1.getHeight() - ship_clearence);
        ship2.setSize(125, 125);
        ship2.setLocation((int) ((win_size / 2) - (ship1.getWidth() / 2)), 0);
        window.add(ship1, 0);
        window.add(ship2, 0);
        window.repaint();
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void move() {
        if (playerKeys.contains(left1)) {
            if (ship1.getX() <= speed) {
                playerKeys.clear();
            } else {
                ship1.setLocation(ship1.getX() - speed, ship1.getY());
            }
        } else if (playerKeys.contains(right1)) {
            if (ship1.getX() + ship1.getWidth() >= win_size - speed) {
                playerKeys.clear();
            } else {
                ship1.setLocation(ship1.getX() + speed, ship1.getY());
            }
        }
        if (playerKeys.contains(left2)) {
            if (ship2.getX() <= speed) {
                playerKeys.clear();
            } else {
                ship2.setLocation(ship2.getX() - speed, ship2.getY());
            }
        } else if (playerKeys.contains(right2)) {
            if (ship2.getX() + ship2.getWidth() >= win_size - speed) {
                playerKeys.clear();
            } else {
                ship2.setLocation(ship2.getX() + speed, ship2.getY());
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == timer) {
            move();
        }
    }

    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Set<Integer> keys;
        private Integer action;
        private boolean released;

        public MoveAction(Set<Integer> keys, Integer action, boolean released) {
            this.keys = keys;
            this.action = action;
            this.released = released;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (released) {
                keys.remove(action);
            } else {
                keys.add(action);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So since your so driven that the grid is a good example, let me show you the problems with it. 1. It doesn't say which imports I need for just key bindings. So I don't know which imports are relevant. 2. It has another class that extends, so is that nessasary in order to make key binding work? Like I have to extend a class for key bindings? 3. Do the addkeybindings normally go in like a main method type of method area or is that specific to this example? 4. What does it mean by action? Is that where I would put my sprite? 5. If I have to extend, does the action perform have to go in the extend

Comment: @BobG. *"1. It doesn't say which imports I need for just key bindings"* - It does, but, you will have to read other relevant examples (like those in the key bindings tutorial) and the JavaDocs to fully understand which imports are most relevant - no answer will give you an absolute answer to JUST that question

Comment: @BobG. *"2. It has another class that extends, so is that nessasary in order to make key binding work?"* - Key bindings only work a `JComponent` based classes. Because of extending from or using a `JFrame` directly has issues and limitations, I personally like to start with a `JPanel` as my base class, it solves a lot of other issues

Comment: @BobG. *"3. Do the addkeybindings normally go in like a main method type of method area or is that specific to this example?"* - No, the example clearly shows where they can be established, as a general rule, they should be setup by the class which is responsible for managing them, in the case of the examples, that tends to be the `JPanel` I use as a based class

Comment: @BobG. *"4. What does it mean by action? Is that where I would put my sprite?"* - Since the `Action` is what will be triggered when the key is pressed AND the example shows the component been moved within it, that would be a reasonable assumption

Comment: @BobG. *"5. If I have to extend, does the action perform have to go in the extend"* - I have no idea what that means, but `Action` is a `class` which means in order to use it, it's easier to simple extend it and encapsulate the functionality you want within it (by overriding the `actionPerformed` method), this simply makes the code more portable

Comment: @BobG. Now you have three examples, plus links to the tutorial, it's now up to you to take the information provided and adapt it to your needs. The intention here is to provide a learning ground from which you can grow and develop a better understanding of how the API works and how you can use. Break the examples, move things around, see what it does

Comment: So I talked to my professor since I couldn't work on it last night because of this. He fixed my code with 1 line of code. He has a doctorate degree in Computer Science. He said key binding is a more advance tech nech, but you do not need it has all you have to do because I was working with buttons and keyboard is request focus. Now I did not put up my other class so that isn't fair to you to say it is your fault. However I know this site has a problem with people posting all their code, so I was trying to follow that rule.

Comment: My professor thinks it is good to do this more advance thing like not using null layout if you have like a lot of experience in the field. However, for new people like me for example, it is not a good idea to set them with a advance tool. You wouldn't have a 5 year old start reading college material would you? He thinks key listener and null layout is fine for a starter, but not necessary for someone who has many years in the field. He thinks many times on stack overflow you get people who says use these advance technique when sometimes it is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: I think it is sad how people dislike by down voting on a question just because the new person isn't using an advance technique. Anyways, I am going to post the answer for using key listener, so new people aren't stuck trying to use an advance technique and forced to restructure their entire code just because people with many years under their belt have to see you use a advance technique even though its just a small project that isn't going up online for millions of people to use or something. Maybe when I get more years in, I will sit down and try to learn key binding.

Comment: @BobG. I understand your point of view, *"He thinks key listener and null layout is fine for a starter"* - So they think that teaching a beginner bad habits as a foundation skill is a good idea ... I'm not looking forward to been your lead in the future, I was trying to show you "good habits" to develop a strong foundation.

Comment: @BobG. *"However I know this site has a problem with people posting all their code, so I was trying to follow that rule"* - I think you misunderstand the rules, [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is what we generally ask for - something that is compilable and can be run, so we have better context to the issue

Comment: @BobG. *"it is not a good idea to set them with a advance tool"* - Key Bindings aren't an "advanced" tool and neiter are layouts, they are core fundamental aspects of the API - Animation and threading, are "advanced" tools

Comment: @BobG. *"He thinks many times on stack overflow you get people who says use these advance technique when sometimes it is just a matter of opinion"* - Then you misunderstand the purpose of SO, it's not a matter of "opinion", it's mostly a matter of experience and community aggreement. SO is, after all a forum for professional programming support, but we also like helping people who are just starting out in the field.

Comment: @BobG. *"forced to restructure their entire code just because people with many years under their belt have to see you use a advance technique even though its just a small project that isn't going up online for millions of people to use or something"* - perfect practice makes perfect - the size of the project is irrelevent, applying good pratices to what ever you do builds good habits and prevents you from falling into bad traps, I'd prefer to provide you and others a strong foundation of good habits

Comment: @BobG. *"I think it is sad how people dislike by down voting on a question just because the new person isn't using an advance technique"* - Then you misunderstand why the question was down voted, but no matter how many different ways we'd try and explain it to you, you wound't accept the fact that the question was poorly suited to the site

Comment: I have stated why your example wasn't a good one many time and you still refused to give another example or make current code work. Key binding maybe a starter for you, but that doesn't mean its a beginning technique. In reality its more advance. My professor says we don't even cover key binding in our college as key listener is just fine. He could make an argument against you for why key listener is just fine. I think you should have tried to make my current code work, but make a suggestion to use key binding instead of trying to force me to use key binding.

Comment: @BobG. I'm also a martial arts instructor, so understand the point I'm coming from, I would never teach a student any "bad habit" regardless of how experienced they were, I'd always be focused on teaching the from a foundation of strong basic habits - I take the same approach with coding. Java is a object oriented language, that provides a series of common traits and tools that can be used to make coding easier and more flexible - which is why I rely on inheritance as well as following a basic concept of "separation of responsibility", which should all be core concepts taught to all students

Comment: @BobG. "I have stated why your example wasn't a good one many time and you still refused to give another example or make current code work. Key binding maybe a starter for you, but that doesn't mean its a beginning technique"* - Again, I'm trying to show you the "correct" solution to your problem, which solve the core fundamental issue with `KeyListener` - I'm not forcing you to do anything, it's up to you to decide if it will work for you know or not, that does not make it wrong.

Comment: @BobG. "My professor says we don't even cover key binding in our college as key listener is just fine"* - I'm sure he thinks he can - but he'd still be fundamentally wrong on the key aspects of why the community recommends against them, but this is not the time or place ;)

Comment: You're trying to force key binding on to me because I would have never had solved the problem if it wasn't for my professor because you can't tell me to add one simple line of code. Do you understand why I am a little angry with you? Restructure entire code regardless of how big or small it is or add one simple line of code? I pick the simple line of code. Next time work with the code and make a suggestion. Keep in mind that a "good habit" might be really complicated and thus do not teach beginners complicated things, work up to it. I disagree with your method because of the flaw that I stated

Comment: @BobG. "I think you should have tried to make my current code work"* - And this is your fundamental issue - you're not interested in learning how to be better, you just want it to work. I'm sorry that I'm not willing to break my fundamental principles to show a solution which is unlikely to work reliably or which teaches you bad habits - I do, however, wish you theist of luck in your studies

Comment: Ok keep forcing people to modify their entire code. Best to luck to you on your teaching of complicated but "good" practices. Complicated things come later in my opinion.